# Invalid content was found starting with element 'property'

Tags: java, xml

I got this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 45 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 45; columnNumber: 42; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'property'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.
```

This is `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.sajjad" />


<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"   
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:packagesToScan="com.sajjad"
      p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties" />


<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>

<!--    <util:properties id="hibernateProperties" >
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
</util:properties>-->

</beans>
```

And `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" `xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee`
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">`
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I got this error for `<util>` tag too:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 52 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 52; The prefix "util" for element "util:properties" is not bound.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an end tag `</beans>` here in your `applicationContext.xml`

For util, you need the namespace declared, too...

```
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
```

You can do something like...

```
<util:map id="hibernateConfig" >
    <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <!-- Other properties -->
</util:map>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
..
..
p:hibernateProperties-ref ="hibernateConfig"/>
```

Comment: No, it exists, o forgot to add it.

Comment: And you are still having the same issue?

Comment: Edited my answer to help you more.